# Como inserir dados separados?

Tags: c#, mysql

Eu quero inserir dados em uma tabela no banco de dados, porém existem campos não obrigatórios, como devo proceder em relação a isso, pois não consigo realizar o comando dessa maneira por ex:

```
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO item VALUES( " +
                    "@id_item, " +
                    "@nome, " +
                    "@descricao, " +
                    "@imagem, " +
                    "@categoria); ",conexao)
```

Por exemplo o campo `descricao`não é obrigatório, se ele estiver vazio não posso enviar os dados para o banco, como poderia resolver isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode adicionar a coluna descrição condicionalmente, ou seja, apenas se a sua variável que representa o valor da descrição estiver preenchida que nós iremos inserir os dados na coluna.

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO item (id_item, " +                                                                                          
                                                          "nome, " +
                                                          (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(descricao) ? "descricao, " : "") +
                                                          "imagem, " +
                                                          "categoria, " +
                                              "VALUES(@id_item, " +
                                                     "@nome, " +
                                                     (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(descricao) ? "@descricao, " : "") +
                                                     "@imagem, " +
                                                     "@categoria); ", conexao);
```

Nesse exemplo considerei que sua variável se chama `descricao`.

Comment: valeu me ajudou muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Se você deseja usar uma camada mais leve para trabalhar com o banco, ou seja, usar diretamente o ADO, sugiro usar o [Dapper](https://dapper-tutorial.net/). Ele é apenas um wrapper para o ADO, porém com algumas funcionalidades e extensões que podem te auxiliar.